# Flow union type refinement defeated by filter

Tags: javascript, flowtype

The example can be found @ [flowtype.org/try](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBTAHgBzgJwBcxCBPHDMAQQGNCBLOAOzAF5UxOwBvAHxPIYAXGADkVAMIAVAJIB5AHIBGUQBowOAIal4mgCYiAzoXz0mAczC8Avhys9+ZCiPHT5CgExqN23QbBMAK4AtgBGGPhWtpz8fALOYpKyigDMolHoNMzGJAAWZuaGbGAAFMaahMLU+PjaADxBYREAfMUA2gC66pp0jEwitAzMAJQDNfWN4fitrK3cdvRQpT1DTAB0TpSs24luil7DPHac+BiEgfgs5ZVrUPQwlfglJYT5FoezPGCn55d5BWAAIQ7FZ9NZaHRwfRgazDOzWMAYGCGSjzLjfM4XK6ECoYeGoWyoV4FQwlNpKdQAVi6X02LiS7i86ghfhElJhcNQWSYOX0emKZRxlREkwixQADN1eswBtKmKMAiEpmw5gsliVQcwNoI2DtXMlPKJDmiuD8sWBrpQANRgTXrFlQvTwxHI1HHDG-bG4-GEvklSW0wT0vaG5m+R1sjmoIA). Here I would expect the type refinement in the conditional to work in both examples, while it only works in the simpler one. When I introduce `Array.filter` the refinement does not take effect. Is this a bug in Flow or mis-usage on my part?

```
/* @flow */

export type Action =
    {| type: 'ACTION1', payload: string |}
  | {| type: 'ACTION2', payload: number |}
  | {| type: 'ACTION3' |}

const things = (state: Array<number> = [], action: Action): Array<number> => {
  if (action.type === 'ACTION2') {
    return state.filter((thing) => { return thing !== action.payload })
  } else {
    return state
  }
}

things([1, 5], { type: 'ACTION2', payload: 5 })

const add = (state: number = 0, action: Action): number => {
  if (action.type === 'ACTION2') {
    return state + action.payload
  } else {
    return state
  }
}

add(0, { type: 'ACTION2', payload: 5 })
```

generates the following errors:

```
10:     return state.filter((thing) => { return thing !== action.payload })
                                                                 ^ property `payload`. Property not found in
6:   | {| type: 'ACTION3' |}       ^ object type
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simply a matter of Flow aggressively invalidating type refinements. Flow does not know what `filter` is going to do with the callback you pass. Maybe it's going to save it and call it later. Flow also doesn't realize that nothing else reassigns `action`. As far as it's concerned, `action` might be reassigned to `{type: 'ACTION3'}` by the time the callback is called. Pulling the payload out into a `const` solves the issue:

```
const payload = action.payload;
return state.filter((thing) => { return thing !== payload })
```