# Flow errors when dealing with nullable types

Tags: redux, flowtype

I have working on a redux reducer with the following state:

```js
 export type WishlistState = {
  +deals: ?DealCollection,
  +previousWishlist: ?(Deal[]),
  +currentWishlist: ?(Deal[]),
  +error: ?string
};
export type DealCollection = { [number]: Deal };

export const initialState: WishlistState = {
  deals: null,
  previousWishlist: null,
  currentWishlist: null,
  error: null
};

export default function wishlistReducer(
  state: WishlistState = initialState,
  action: WishlistAction
): WishlistState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_DEALS_SUCCESS":
      return { ...state, deals: action.deals };
    case types.GET_WISHLIST_SUCCESS:
      console.log(action);
      const currentWishlist: Deal[] = action.wishlistIds.map(
      // ATTENTION: THIS LINE HERE
        d => state.deals[d]
      );
      return {
        ...state,
        currentWishlist,
        previousWishlist: null,
        error: null
      };
    // ...other cases
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The line I've flagged with the comment is getting a flow error on the `d` in the 
brackets:

```
Cannot get `state.deals[d]` because an index signature declaring the expected key/value type is missing in null or undefined.
```

This is happening because of the type annotation: `deals: ?DealCollection`, which is made clearer if I change the line to this:

```js
d => state.deals && state.deals[d]
```

Which moves the error to `state.deals`; and the idea is that if `state.deals` is null, then the callback returns null (or undefined), which is not a acceptable return type for a `map` callback.

I tried this and I really thought it would work:

```js
      const currentWishlist: Deal[] = !state.deals
        ? []
        : action.wishlistIds.map(d => state.deals[d]);
```

It would return something acceptable if there are no `deals` is null, and never get to the `map` call. But this puts the error back on the `[d]` about the index signature.

Is there any way to make Flow happy in this situation?

Comment: What is the type definition of `WishlistAction`? Something like `{ type: string, deals: DealCollection, wishlistIds: number[] }`?

Comment: Is [this](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAIhCGAbKBeKBnYAnAlgOwHMBuKAelKgGN48oAjaAdwAt5gIA3CLAKFElgJEAYQD2iRBErAco2mgDeUANp4ArgFsGWALoAuQUigBfIjwAmUxPCzQONqJaToDAfjhIxEqTLklyUDRIogSiauhQwKIYwGwQAHROiOgWVjZ2Dow46MyI2cAAkuYuUOpa3Mo6-hRBiCFhEVGB0rJ48Vk5eZhFKZRymFRqWLZ4wADq2bn5Bh6IlahQHVPdxfEa8GAAFOaoAHyOQujK5joAlERAA) a good summary of your issue?

Comment: I suppose that's a basic summary, yes. The relevant action type (`WishlistAction` is a joint type with 10+ subtypes) is ```export type GetWishlistSuccessAction = {
  type: "GET_WISHLIST_SUCCESS",
  wishlistIds: number[]
};```

Answer (score 0):

Flow invalidates type refinements whenever a variable may have been modified. In your case, the thought of checking `!state.deals` is a good start; however, Flow will invalidate the fact that `state.deals` must have been a `DealCollection` because (theoretically) you could be modifying it in your `map` function. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43076553/11308639 for more information on Flow type invalidation.

In your case, you can "cache" `state.deals` when you have refined it as a `DealCollection`. For example,

```
type Deal = string; // can be whatever
type DealCollection = { [number]: Deal };
declare var deals: ?DealCollection; // analogous to state.deals
declare var wishlistIds: number[]; // analogous to action.wishlistIds
let currentWishlist: Deal[] = [];
if (deals !== undefined && deals !== null) {
  const deals_: DealCollection = deals;
  currentWishlist = wishlistIds.map(d => deals_[d]);
}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAIhCGAbKBeKBnYAnAlgOwHMBuKAelKgGN48oAjaAdwAt5gIA3CLAKFElgJEAYQD2iRBErAco2mgDeUANp4ArgFsGWALoAuQUigBfIjwAmUxPCzQONqJaToDAfjhIxEqTLklyUDRIogSiauhQwKIYwGwQAHROiOgWVjZ2Dow46MyI2cAAkuYuUOpa3Mo6-hRBiCFhEVGB0rJ48Vk5eZhFKZLAVGpYtnjAAOrZufkGHoiVqCpVPDgAZlAAFEkRAIQoaGp4lsv4EOZQAGRnjkLbu6VqEgCUUAo8UFRymFfOAPrTQl6SFpyeabMxvSiDYZjCZdfpoDqTbrFeIaeBgDaoAB8X2S32U5h0DzMxiAA)

that way you can access `deals_` without Flow invalidating the refinement.